# Simply PDO select not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is driving me mad.

The following gives me output:

```
 function transaction_graph(){
    $date_start = "2017-08-04 01:51:29";
    $date_end = "2017-08-05 01:51:29";
    $trans_start = 1;
    $trans_end = 60;
    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $query = "SELECT dtime, url, sale 
    FROM sales
    WHERE dtime BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
    ORDER BY
    dtime ASC
    LIMIT :trans_start, :trans_end";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start_date', $date_start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end_date', $date_end,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':trans_start', $trans_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':trans_end',  $trans_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
    }
```

This function is a method of a class.  However when I replace the variables in the bindParam of the PDO procedure with $this->date_start etc and comment out the variables I am not getting a query result.  Yet these properties of the object are certainly defined as I am echoing them out successfully.  Moreover they are the exact same values as the strings I defined the variables as when testing this out.  Lastly I've also checked for errors by catching but I got no error.

Anybody have any idea what I'm missing?

This is how I am defining the object properties and calling the method:

```
$trans_start = $stocks->trans_start = 1;
$trans_end = $stocks->trans_end = 60;

$end = date('"Y-m-d h:i:s"', strtotime('now'));
$start = date('"Y-m-d h:i:s"', strtotime('- 1 hours'));

$stocks->date_start = $start;
$stocks->date_end = $end;

$stmt = $stocks->transaction_graph();

$sales_array = [];
$max = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
var_dump($row);
$sales_array[] = $row;
//find the greatest sales value in the range
if($row['sale'] > $max)
{
    $max = $row['sale'];
}
}
```

That var dump returns everything - i.e. code works - only if i define the class method as originally posted; as soon as the variables at the top of the function are commented out and i put the object properties inside the bindParam i get nothing...

Comment: What happens if you change `:start_date` and `:end_date` to date parameters rather than string parameters?

Comment: I will have to check.  But if a string works the way described above then it should work through swapping the variables for the properties of the object shouldnt it?

Comment: so the provided code work ? and if you change it into a method it doesnt work ? what is the expected output ? what is the output ? can you provide a var_dump of $stmt ?

Comment: The above code works.  When i delete the variables at the top of the function and instead bind the parameters as follows (':start_date', $this->date_start, PDO::PARAM_STR), instead of above i get no output.  Yet these properties are echoed out successfully so are defined

Comment: you shold provide an example of the not working class its initiation and how you call the method.

Comment: `'"Y-m-d h:i:s"'` - This is wrong. Remove either double or single quotes.

Comment: Jesus wept.  That was it.  Thank you very much.  Profuse apologies for the now misleading question title.  I am still quite new to all this.  Thanks again

Comment: Next time turn error reporting and PDO exception mode on. You would see that MySQL complains about "Incorrect datetime value". - I vote to close it as a  typo question.

Comment: Besides the problem Paul mentioned, use the capital H (24h-notation) instead of lowercase (12h-notation) in your date format, otherwise it would lead to some unexpected results sooner or later